# get the basename of the project

Tags: php

I want to get  the project name 'video' which is in www folder.I have created a file in a folder structure video/profiles/commons/module/modulename/test.php

in my test.php I have the base path `$basepath=__DIR__;` which returns `file:///C:/wamp64/www/video/profiles/commons/modules/modulename/` .I want to get only the project name 'video'

Comment: print_r( preg_split("/\//",ltrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "/"))[0]);

Comment: it works if you get the dir thru  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] but using  file:///C:/wamp64/www/ it won't

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```
$path = dirname(`__FILE__`);
echo basename($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
$project = basename(__DIR__ . '/../../../../');
echo $project; // video
```

Answer (score -1):

use regex like the following to manipulate the string

```
(?<=www\/)[^\/]+
```